# ¿Why some classes of tailwind don't work?

Tags: css, laravel, tailwind-css

I have a project created with Laravel 8, Jetstream, I've installed Tailwind CSS and fontawesome-free too.

When I use this classes like that:

```
<i class="fa fa-user-circle text-white cursor-pointer text-6xl"></i>
```

`text-white` and `cursor-pointer` works perfectly but "text-6xl" don't

if I use `style="font-size: 60px"` this works, but the class of Tailwind don't

Comment: works fine https://jsbin.com/viqapizige/edit?html,output

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that using laravel 8 with scss, but the output for your tailwind is css, try changing it and it should work.

Comment: it's supposed to I've intalled Tailwind  for don't write my own css styles, I need that all classes of tailwind works

Comment: maybe you imported scss instead of css?

Comment: nope, only some classes don't work, if there was a bad import, no one class would working

Comment: don't working about scss, the only way this work is execute `nmp run watch` on the console, so this refresh all changes and show the correct css on the page

Comment: you don't refresh when you make changes?! thats not my problem

Answer (score 0):

Run `npm run dev`

Not all of tailwind css classes will be available unless you build dev assets.

You can also `npm run dev watch` to watch the files and recompile when one of them changes.